# iOS: displaying JSON Array in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uisearchbar

i have a JSON Dict in this format

```
{
  "382" : "sudhir kumar",
  "268" : "David  ",
  "385" : "aayush test",
  "261" : "Mike watson",
  "277" : "TestDrivers Driver",
  "381" : "sudhir kumar",
  "380" : "sudhir kumar",
  "383" : "asdfgh asdfgh",
  "376" : " "
}
```

I have to display it in UISearchBar. Someone please help me to solve it as when i select any name from search its respective Id also selected

I am using the following code it filtered name but not their related ID's with name

My code is:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;
{


    tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverNameArray];
    //NSString *stringToSearch = textField.text;

    tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverIdArray];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",searchText]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

    //NSPredicate * predicateid = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",stringToSearch];

    NSArray *tempresults = [DriverNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (tempresults.count > 0)
    {
        tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
        tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
    }
    [SEarchTable reloadData];
    //return  YES;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried show your code?

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted code pertaining to what you've already tried, so I won't post code that directly gives you the solution to your question.

Your best bet is to create an array of dictionaries holding a value for the names and a value for the ID. When you display your data, display the names from the array by `myArray[@"name"]` convention. You can then get the index of that object and then run `[myArray objectAtIndex:myCalculatedIndex][@"id"]` to get the ID.

There are actually many ways to solve this problem, but this is one of them.